# PHP page crash PDO with 85000 result. Max number of returning rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have code in PHP where I'm calling in PDO all rows from a table where the table contains 83000 rows.

The page crash before it finishes loading.

Any Idea what is the problem.

I try the same table but with the first 10000 results and it work!

My php max_execution time is set at.

```
max_execution_time = 18000
```

And memory limit

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Here is my PDO class

```
class Database{

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($login, $password, $database_name, $host = 'localhost'){
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$database_name;host=$host", $login, $password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->pdo->exec("set names utf8");
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @param bool|array $params
     * @return PDOStatement
     */
    public function query($query, $params = false){
        if($params){
            $req = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
            $req->execute($params);
        }else{
            $req = $this->pdo->query($query);
        }
        return $req;
    }

    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

And her is my php query

```
$schedules = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `schedules` ORDER BY id",[])->fetchall();

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {

}
```

Comment: You're gonna need to give us alot more info than that.

Comment: If you include a stacktrace or error someone will be able to tell you for certain, but my guess is you're running out of memory. You should really grab the data in pages or use a cursor.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Could this be related to a limitation of runtime, as in: executing your script takes more time than allowed in `max_execution_time`?

Comment: any chance of a log?  Maybe an error message?  Also, what are you doing with 83,000 rows in 1 query?

Comment: Why are you displaying 85k rows at once on a single page, in the first place? What kind of user will read 85k rows? Maybe you should use pagination.

Comment: I don't need to display all of those line. I need to compair data from one table to the other. As soon as I select more then maybe 30,000 row the code stop executing after 1-2 secondes. My max_execution time is at 2 minutes.

Comment: to quote @TimHinz - we need 'alot more info than that' .  Check you error logs, maybe post the query and table structure, try and get an output from php as to what the crash is

Comment: I just edit my post and Add a lot more info. My php database class. My php current setting...

Comment: You say you are comparing one table with another. If you tell us what you are comparing, I bet someone could write you a query that would do the compare and only return you what you actually want to see

Comment: I'd second @RiggsFolly - I think if you are selecting an entire table to then compare it to another table you should be able to do this in a. since sensible query and also mysql to filter the rows to return a proper result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP instances on web servers usually have limited RAM. You are probably hitting the limit. Usually result sets are *buffered.* That means PHP slurps the entire result set, all 85K rows, into memory at once, and that may exceed the available RAM for your PHP process.

You need to [use an *unbuffered* result set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php).  PHP reads it a row at a time. So, you can process each row individually.

Something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO( ... );
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$uresult = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM big_table");
if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       /* process the row */
   }
}
```

But, beware. PHP also has a [time limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) on each execution. You may exceed it when you process that many rows.

You can consider using `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` in your query to process your rows in chunks, rather than all at once.

Comment: @MathieuB in your php query this bit is important: `->fetchall();`.  That one little thing is where you try to load the entire result set into memory.

Comment: @ConorMancone any idea how I can add this to my database class?